# It is possible :Two references to one column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

Is it possible to allow two optional foreign key?

**For example:**
table a (id, nameA)
table b(id nameB)
table c(id ,name)
that the name in table c is a foreign key
 and it can contracts or the id from table **a** or the id from table **b**.

**If its possible, what the way to create it?**

Comment: No, you can reference a foreign key only from one table at once. Perhaps you have to merge tablea with tableb?

Comment: Its can be an idea, what the way to create its, and how its work?